Why can I unpack a Python set when sets are unordered?
I am quite used to unpacking sequences in Python like:
my_tuple = (1, 2, 3)

a, b, c = my_tuple

I have noticed that I can also do it with sets:
my_set = set((1, 2, 3))

a, b, c = my_set

Why can I do this? I mean, it makes perfect sense for lists and tuples which are ordered. But how does this make sense for a set which is not ordered?
How can I be sure which value ends up in which variable on the left-hand side? Or maybe I do not quite understand ordered vs. unordered?
a,b,c = set((3,2,1))

Here a==1, b==2, and c==3 illustrates what I mean is ambiguous.

its in ascending order of the hash value of the elements

It is undefined which value ends up in which variable. So you can only use that syntax when the order is not important.

@ken thats not true. it is an implementation detail, but it is not "undefined"

@muzzletov "ascending order of the hash value" is practically random for all intents and purposes…

Sets are iterables, and you can unpack iterables into variables. It's not for Python to protect you from doing so. It's up to you to judge the usefulness of your code.

@deceze depends on what the actual implementation is. if you want to make use of it - and can, which you could knwoing this detail and being able to rely on the implementation -, it is useful to know that.

@muzzletov For all practical intents and purposes, I don't think anyone is going to predict the order of sets based on C implementation details. At least I'd hope so.

If someone wants to use the order of the hash values, they should use the hash function to implement it, not exploit CPython's implementation of set.

Hash randomization means you may not be able to rely on a fixed hashing for str and bytes values anyway.

If you have a bag full of balls, the balls are not in any order inside the bag, but when you pick them, you pick them in some order, because you need to first pick one, then another... This creates an order, which is not necessarily the order in which you previously put the balls in the bag

@Elerium115 this may not be analogous. please dont use analogies like these. your bag of balls example may turn out to be in complete correspondance right for every finite try - that is, order of putting in the bag is picking out of bag. but in this case the order is fixed and based on the hash.

a,b,c = set((3,2,1)) should be c,b,a = set((3,2,1))

@chepner you can disable the randomization. But, I am not suggesting to do so.

@muzzletov Yes; it's on by default, but can be disabled, or (more usefully for testing) made deterministic. (Or put another way, hashing is parametric, and you can either let Python choose that parameter randomly or specify a fixed parameter at runtime.)

You need to distinguish between the set, which has no ordering, and the set iterator, which has an arbitrary order derived from the underlying hash values of the set. a, b, c = some_set is really a, b, c = iter(some_set) in disguise.
>>> type({1,2,3})
<class 'set'>
>>> type(iter({1,2,3}))
<class 'set_iterator'>


I think you have the wrong expectations about what "unordered" means.
A set clearly has some order - you can iterate over it, convert it to a list, and, as you've seen, unpack it. Moreover, given the same elements and the same Python version, the set will always have the same order.
This doesn't mean you can assume anything about a set's order. Specifically, the unpacking example you shared is a very bad idea. You'll clearly get a, b and c populated with the elements of the set, but you can't make any assumptions on which variable will get which value. If it doesn't matter, by all means, go for it. If it does, you should use some ordered collection (such as a list), or explicitly handle sorting them.

In Python 3.12 if you run:
my_set = set((3, 2, 1))
a, b, c = my_set
print(a, b, c)

The result is always the same 1 2 3. This is due to how the current internal implementation of Python works for small integers. (I remember that it was different in previous versions.) This behavior is not reliable and may change in the future. Sets should be treated as unordered.
For another example, if you run:
my_set = set(('text3', 'text3', 'text1'))
a, b, c = my_set
print(a, b, c)

What will be printed will be different each time.
If you want them to maintain the order, you could, for example, sort them first:
a, b, c = sorted(my_set)

Why unpacking sets
Unpacking sets can have different use cases in function arguments, set operations, and more. Here are some examples:

Function arguments

def add(a, b, c):
    return a + b + c

numbers = {1, 2, 3}
result = add(*numbers)


Combining Sets and other iterables

set1 = {1, 2, 3}
list1 = [4, 5, 6]
combined = [*set1, *list1]

There are many other use cases as well.

You can unpack any iterable object, here some examples
a, b, c = "abc"

a, b, c = iter("abc")

The previous cases are order preserving.
What happen with a set which is not ordered?
s = set("abc")
print(s)
# {'c', 'b', 'a'}

a, b, c = s
print(a, b, c)
# c b a

The simultaneous initialization of the variables follow the "internal" order of the data structure.
